# Clonezilla SCSI HDD cloning problem

Tags: hardware, hard-disk, disk-image, scsi, old-hardware-adaptation

I'm trying to clone or take images of old SCSI hard disks. I use Clonezilla and at the last phase, it's written "no input". This is for 68 pin SCSI HDD. In another case, I can't see the hard disk at start and when I try taking image of HDD, it's said "...kernel is too old...".this is for 50 pin old SCSI HDD.

When I try with new SCSI disks, I have no problem, I can clone disks but with old SCSI disks, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used dd command on a Ubuntu installed computer, using terminal. It worked for me but there may be differences due to file system.

Answer (score 2):

You may have some luck by selecting option 2 in Clonezilla: "Use the same CPU level with that of this DRBL server."

[Source](https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Clonezilla_server_edition/thread/38dd143e/)